# Node js functionality for mongoose

Tags: node.js, authentication, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have created a simple login and sign up page using node js and mongodb. I have a database which contains username, email-id and password fields. I have to display the username on the screen when the user inputs the email-id and password on the login page. How to access the respective username when email-id is given? I'm not getting how to proceed further. Can anybody help?

```
app.post('/login.html', function(req, res){
// new code should come over here
User.findOne({email: req.body.email, password1: req.body.password1}, function(err, user){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.write("Not found");
    }
    else if(user){
        console.log("login successful");
        res.render('next',{success:"Login successful!!",name:req.body.email});
    }
    else {
        console.log('Invalid');
        res.render('login',{failed:"Login unsuccessful!!"});

    }
});
```

});

Here I'm using the email-id which the user gives on the login page. But instead I have to display the username which is there in the database using the email id. Some one please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO! If the login is successful you should have access to the `user`, can you `console.log(user)` and check if the username property exists? If it does, the problem could be in the fact that you are passing  `{name: req.body.email}`, maybe you want to pass `{name: user.username}`.

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks a lot!!